# Number Format Exception, really stuck

Tags: java, exception

hereis my code.... I am getting a NumberFormatException and idk whow to solve it.. newbie and totally stuck, really need the help

```
public class AcccountArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Scan the file and save account details to array
        File file = new File ("customers.txt");
        System.out.println("Path : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        try{
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("customers.txt");
                    String[][] Account = new String[Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())][3];

                    for(int i=0;i<Account.length;i++)
                    {
                        Account[i][0]=scanner.nextLine();
                        //System.out.println(Account[i][0]);
                        Account[i][1]=scanner.nextLine();
                        //System.out.println(Account[i][1]);
                        Account[i][2]=scanner.nextLine();
                        //System.out.println(Account[i][2]);
                    }
                    scanner.close();
```

error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "customers.txt"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at AcccountArray.main(AcccountArray.java:15)
```

li. 15 is

```
String[][] Account = new String[Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())][3];
```

Comment: Solved the problem with the scanner, but now I am getting a FileNotFOiundException...ready to pull hair

Comment: You're not looking in the right location for the File (or perhaps better, for the resource). 1+ to @Reimeus's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the constructor for `Scanner` that accepts a `File` so that the scanner instance is not using a `String` source:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("customers.txt"));
```

Since you already have this reference you can use

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: now I am getting FileNotFoundException: customers.txt 
 at AcccountArray.main(AcccountArray.java:14)

Comment: but customers is certainly a file

Comment: The file is not located in the application path. Make sure the file is located in `new File("customers.txt").getAbsolutePath()`